# Functional for loop in Scala/Chisel

Tags: scala, functional-programming, chisel

I'm trying to find functional equivalent of the following algorithm (not really Scala or Chisel syntax):

```
val x = Wire(Vec(n, UInt(L.W)))
val z = Wire(UInt(L.W))
var y = 0;
for (i <- 0 to (L-1)) {
   y = 0;
   for (j <- 0 to (n-1)) {
      y = y || x(j, i)
   }
   z(i) = y;
}
```

### Original Problem

I have `n` buses, each having `L` wires. I want to create an `OR` gate that has respective bits from each bus and produce an output. The reduction operators that I know works on a single bus. For example, I could use `x(1).orR` to create an OR gate, but how can I achieve this on an array of buses. I'm assuming Chisel requires all hardware-related behavioral models to be functional in nature. So, my question is two fold:

1. Do I always need to write behavioral models in Chisel using functional programming?
2. Can I create a functional for loop that achieves the above.

Comment: See Kamyar's response for answer to the main question. I just want to mention that when you write Chisel, you are _not_ writing a behavioral model. Rather, you're writing a program that generates the hardware when it executes. Chisel provides primitives like `Reg` and `Wire` and hardware types like `UInt`, `Vec`, and `Bundle`. Your Scala code is a program that runs, composing these primitives together along with operations on them (like bitwise OR: `|`) to construct a hardware graph that we emit as Verilog. Hope this helps!

Comment: @JackKoenig So you mean that I cannot arbitrary define a method using `def` that implements a combinational logic and expect Chisel to produce optimized hardware? In other words, while describing hardware, we're supposed to design the hardware in terms of so called Chisel primitives like Reg, RegNext, etc. ? I was assuming that reduce function itself is a behavior being modeled as an OR gate.

Comment: You can write arbitrary Scala composing Chisel primitives together and it will generate hardware. Chisel will perform simple optimizations, but it leaves the real optimizations to your standard synthesis flow. When I say Chisel isn't behavioral synthesis, I mean it isn't analyzing the Scala AST and trying to generate hardware. Rather, it just runs the Scala program effectively unrolls things like for loops. Chisel itself does no synthesis, it's just a library that provides the primitives that designers can use to build their own abstractions.

Comment: Here's a talk I gave at Latch Up in Portland last year where I try to explain this with a detailed example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dbOi_Gboi_0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```scala
z := x.reduce(_ | _)
```

or use *tree reduction* for a more efficient hardware description:

```scala
io.z := io.x.reduceTree(_ | _)
```

See the generated Verilog here:
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/kammoh/lxOjBBtXTJ69bqgYVClexw/2

Scala is multi paradigm programming language which supports functional, object oriented, and even imperative models. You don't *have to* use functional programming paradigm in Chisel, but it can definitely make your code more elegant and readable.

Comment: Great answer, thanks Kamyar. I'd just note that while `reduceTree` uses fewer nodes and thus looks nicer in the Verilog, it should synthesize exactly the same as the linear `reduce`.

Comment: Thanks @JackKoenig! I agree that the synthesis tools are likely to infer the same hardware with both descriptions (that’s why I said more efficient hardware “description” and not hardware), but I thought maybe the generated hardware *could* also be different depending on the quality and opted level of the optimization effort that the tool exerts?

Answer (score 1):

I don't do Chisel, so I can't test it, but I think this does the same thing without all those nasty mutable variables.

```
(0 until L).foldLeft((Wire(Vec(n,UInt(L.W))), Wire(UInt(L.W)))){
  case ((x,z),i) =>
    z(i) = (0 until n).foldLeft(0){case (y,j) => y || x(j,i)}
}
```